# Memory segmentation fault in the double linked list implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, iterator

Below I have a implementation of Linked List.

While there may be more errors because I have not yet finished, let's focus at the four functions: pop_front, push_front, push_back, pop_back.

Everything seems working, until I try to implement `push_back`. The testing code throws segmentation fault. I don't have idea why, because like it's pretty symmetric operation to the `push_front` but just at the another end of the list. And the `push_front` just works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include "AbstractList.hxx"

template <class T>
class LinkedList : public AbstractList<T>
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        T value;

        Node *prev;
        Node *next;
    };

    LinkedList()
    {
        guard = new Node;

        guard->prev = nullptr;
        guard->next = nullptr;
    }

    // copy,move construction and assignment are not relevant to the question

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        clear();
    }

    template <class U>
    void push_front(U &&x)
    {
        Node *fresh = new Node;

        fresh->value = std::forward<U>(x);
        fresh->prev = nullptr;
        fresh->next = guard->next;

        guard->next = fresh;

        if (empty())
        {
            guard->prev = fresh;
        }
    }

    T pop_front()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty");

        Node *toDelete = guard->next;

        int temp = toDelete->value;

        guard->next = guard->next->next;

        delete toDelete;

        return temp;
    }

    template <class U>
    void push_back(U &&x)
    {
        Node *fresh = new Node;

        fresh->value = std::forward<U>(x);
        fresh->next = nullptr;

        guard->prev = fresh;

        if (empty())
        {
            guard->next = fresh;
        }
    }
    /*
    T pop_back()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty");

        Node *toDelete = guard->prev;

        int temp = toDelete->value;

        guard->prev = guard->prev->prev;

        delete toDelete;

        return temp;
    }
    */
    struct Iterator
    {
    public:
        Node *ptr;

        Iterator(Node *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_){};

        Iterator &operator++()
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
            return *this;
        }

        Iterator &operator++(int)
        {
            Iterator *temp = this;

            ptr = ptr->next;

            return *temp;
        }

        Iterator &operator--()
        {
            ptr = ptr->prev;
            return *this;
        }

        Iterator &operator--(int)
        {
            Iterator *temp = this;

            ptr = ptr->prev;

            return *temp;
        }

        bool operator==(const Iterator &b)
        {
            return ptr == b.ptr;
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator &b)
        {
            return !operator==(b);
        }

        T &operator*()
        {
            return ptr->value;
        }
    };

    Iterator find(const T &x)
    {
        Iterator point = begin();

        while (point != end())
        {
            if (*point == x)
                return point;
            point++;
        }

        // or end()?
        return nullptr;
    }

    // usuwa cala liste
    void clear()
    {
        Node *current = guard->next;

        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            Node *next = current->next;

            delete current;

            current = next;
        }

        guard->prev = nullptr;
        guard->next = nullptr;
    }

    Iterator erase(Iterator x)
    {
        Iterator point = begin();

        while (point != end())
        {
            if (point == x)
            {
                for (point; point != end(); point++)
                {
                    point = ++x;
                }

                return ++x;
            }

            point++;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    template <class U>
    Iterator insert(Iterator it, U &&x)
    {
        for (Iterator point = it; point != end(); point++)
        {
            (point + 1) = point;
        }

        it = std::forward<U>(x);
    }

    int remove(const T &x)
    {
        int count = 0;

        Iterator point = begin();
        Iterator last = end();

        while (point != last)
        {
            Iterator next = point;
            ++next;

            if (*point == x)
            {
                erase(point);
                count++;
            }

            point = next;
        }

        return count;
    }

    int size()
    {
        Iterator point = begin();

        int count = 0;

        while (point != end())
        {
            count++;
            point++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return guard->next == nullptr;
    }

    Iterator begin() const
    {
        return Iterator(guard->next);
    }
    Iterator end() const
    {
        return Iterator(guard->prev);
    }

private:
    // head = next, prev = tail
    Node *guard;
};

#endif
```

Testing code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


#include "./LinkedList.hxx"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LinkedList<int> l1;


    std::cout << l1.size() << std::endl;

    l1.push_front(1);
    l1.push_front(2);
    l1.push_front(3);

    for (auto itr = l1.begin(); itr != l1.end(); itr++)
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;

    std::cout << "fpops: " << l1.pop_front() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fpops: " << l1.pop_front() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "if empty " << l1.empty() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fpops: " << l1.pop_front() << std::endl;

    for (auto itr = l1.begin(); itr != l1.end(); itr++)
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;

    std::cout << l1.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "if empty " << l1.empty() << std::endl;

    l1.push_back(1);

    std::cout << l1.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm Well, I'm not sure of the exact terminology. The `next` of the guard points at the head of the list, and `prev` at the tail of the list.

Comment: `LinkedList(LinkedList<T> const &other)  { clear();` -- This is broken.  You're calling `clear` on an object that has uninitialized members.  Advice -- get your copy semantics working first, i.e. get the copy constructor and destructor working.  When you do that, the assignment operator becomes simply a `std::swap` call.

Comment: Thank you. If I think, yeah, you are right. I'm still learning the C++ so I got habit from the other languages that uninitialized variables may be just NULL / nullptr. I will fix it.

Comment: Your copy constructor and copy assignment are broken. You don't set up the `prev` pointers, and you're copying `guard->prev` from the original, so both `current` and `temp` point into the ."other" list.

Comment: I don't understand how your code compiles in the first place. Your guard is a `Node`, and you call `guard->head` and `guard->tail`, but the `Node` Type does not have any members called `head` and `tail`.

Comment: `push_back` does not link the previous last node to the new node, or the new node to the previous last node.

Comment: A note about C++. With a few exceptions, it doesn't do anything that could have a performance hit unless you ask for it. Initializing a local variable has a cost. The program could be immediately reading a value into the variable, making a forced initialization an unnecessary cost. You'll find the same thing with bounds checks. Bounds checks have a cost. A proper program never accesses out of bounds, so mandatory bounds checks would be unnecessary. The result: no bounds checks most of the time. Be warned.

Comment: If there is a segment violation, it happens _somewhere_. You can stop there in the debugger (or load the core file, if one was saved). So _where_ does this error occur? Look at the code and examine the contents of your objects at this point. If you can't figure it out yourself, at least you can edit some relevant information into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the debugger. I never used it before so I thought it will be pain to setup but however I was able to track the bug. The segmentation fault was happening at the for loop after first iteration. The `next ` pointer at the previous tail element was not set over another iterations. Now it prints 1, 2, and not the 3 lol but I guess I will figure it out. Thanks much